# Induced norm and powers of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to know when $\| A^p \| \leq \| A \|^p$ holds, especially for $0 < p < 1$. I can show this for integer $p>0$ by applying the definition of induced norm, but I don't know how to handle fractional $p$. I'm assuming A is symmetric and positive definite, so, for example, $p=1/2$ is just the symmetric square root.

I should mention, using matlab for $p = 1/2$ leads me to believe that $\|A^{1/2}\| = \|A\|^{1/2}$.

EDIT: After checking the 1,2,inf norms in matlab, I think the rule is

$\| A^p \| \leq \| A \|^p$ for $p>1$ and $\| A^p \| \geq \| A \|^p$ for $0<p<1$.

Comment: For $p\notin\mathbb N$, the term $||A^p||$ is not even defined for all matrices, even if they are symmetric.

Comment: I think it's ok now that I added positive definite.

Comment: To which norm are you referring? If $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ is induced by the euclidean norm, then we have $A = U \rm{diag}(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n) U^T$ with $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n \geq 0$ the eigenvalues of $A$. It is then easy to show that $\Vert A \Vert = \Vert \rm{diag}(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n) \Vert = \max\{\lambda_i \,|\, i =1, \dots, n\}$. The same argument for $A^p$ (how does this look like in terms of $U$ and the $\lambda_i$?) shows your claim.

Comment: Cool, I forgot the 2 norm was the max eigenvalue. I was thinking in terms of a general induced p norm, but quality for the 2 norm makes the edited hypothesis make a lot more sense.